# How to create a Sentry object and pass it to another folder?

Tags: node.js, angular, sentry

Because the project structure looks like this:

```
  -- folder 1 with node modules that has Sentry angular
  -- folder 2 (a servicelib) with node modules that doesn't have Sentry (I need to use Sentry here)
```

I was told to create a Sentry object in folder 1 and pass it to folder 2... I am not sure how I can do that. Any ideas? I have been stuck on this for weeks and I can use some help...

I tried to install sentry/node in folder 2, but errors keep on popping up and I don't know what was wrong with that.

Comment: Do you habe 2 projects or is this one project with two folders? and why dont you just install sentry in folder 2?

Comment: These two folders are in the same directory but are on the same level, so no common node packages to share between them & they each have their own node packages. I tried to install sentry in folder 2, but for some reasons it keeps on throwing all kinds of errors and I couldn't figure out what was the cause. I fixed some of the errors, but when I actually import sentry into the files, it threw more errors. So I decided to use sentry from folder 1...

Comment: if I understand you right this are two individual projects. If thats true you habe to resolve your errors. you cant just use senry from another projekt. This will threw even more errors